# How to move bootstrap fonts to different folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a standard ASP.NET MVC application with Bootstrap. I moved the "Fonts" folder to "Content/Fonts". Inside the folder there are those `glyphicons-halflings-regular` files.

When I start the application I get a 404 browser error that the `Fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff` and `glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf` file couldn't be found.

How do I configure my project so these files are found?

Comment: Where have you references the fonts?

Comment: I didn't. They might be refrerenced in the project template. How do I find out?

Comment: See your html files or css files for references for the old folder

Comment: Thx! Found it in my bootstrap.css. It works now after updating the file. I'm not very happy with it because when updating bootstrap my changes will be lost. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: I am not sure - the nuget package installs in fixed directories to keep the refereces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution was to update pathes in my bootstrap.css.
(See comments of original question)

Thx meep for your help.

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to update paths in bootstrap.css. However, when you update Bootstrap, your changes will be lost. I'd recommend simply moving your stylesheet as well to keep the hierarchical structure found in the unmodified stylesheet.

For example, if you want to move your fonts in the Contents/Fonts folder (I always hate it being loose in the project root folder too haha), have your styles in the Content/Styles folder so that ../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff (and so on) still references the correct folder.